# Extract text inside brackets into an array, but also nested brackets (C#)

Tags: c#, string, extract

I am working on someone else's templating system. They created this system several years ago. I'm trying to update the code to now include nested string:

The code takes a string that contains a "tag", extracts everything within the [* *] and adds them to an array.

E.g.

```
string message = "Hello, [*database.table.field*]"
```

*NB. The tag is this: [*database.table.field*]

would become:

```
str[0] = database
str[1] = table
str[2] = field
```

For this instance, string.split works fine.

However, I have nested situations like this:

```
string message = "Hello, [*database.table.field.[*database.table.field*]*]"
```

and to compound the problem further; a string may contain 5 elements:

```
string message = "Hello, [*database.table.field.fieldx.fieldy*]"
```

To put it all into perspective; I may end up with a full string like this:

```
string message = "Hello, [*database.table.field*] thank you for your recent student application, I am pleased to inform you that you have been accepted on the, [*database.table.field.[*database.table.field*]*] course. Please can you send your [*database.table.field.fieldx,fieldy*]...
```

What I have tried so far is a combination of string.split and array.length, it has led me to have a lot of if/else statements.

Is there a better solution, I've been stuck on this for a year, and part of the issue is that I am unable to technically convey what I am trying to achieve.

Edit: What I am trying to achieve is;

A) I need to identify every instance of the "tag".
B) I need to split them into a list? so that I can access the values of any tag.

E.g this nested example would become:

```
[*database.table.field.[*database.table.fieldx*]*]

str[0] = database
str[1] = table
str[2] = field

str[0] = database
str[1] = table
str[2] = fieldx
```

I will then query the database using the data in the tags. This:

```
str[0] = database
str[1] = table
str[2] = field
```

I will take to look into the correct DB, Table and field to extract the data: "Marcus", and then replace the tag with Marcus.

Comment: What do you expect as the result of the nested situation - also in your example of 5 elements the final separator is a comma - was that deliberate or a typo - if the former what result do you expect?

Comment: I'm also confused by your requirements. If the input is `string message = "Hello, [*database.table.field.[*database.table.field*]*]"`, what is the expected output?

Comment: Exactly what @PaulF is saying, best would be to include expected output on the cases

Comment: recursion is what you want to find the target strings to split. get the outer most, and keep looping until none found.

Comment: NOTE - edit your question - do not add the expected output as a comment as it does not format nicely.

Comment: Even better - let's look at the bigger picture. What exactly is this code trying to achieve? There's probably a better approach - this templating system probably has a more natural solution.

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I'm not the best at explaining, but I am learning as I read your comments. I have added the edits. Ultimately, I need to replace that contains "tags" queries from the database.

Comment: Regular Expressions. Read about them. I had once similar problem but in php. I was able to find solution with regular expressions. But now I don't remember how to do that.